# Is there a way to split by Custom Delimiter in Spark(with Scala) and not read line by line, to read a set of key, value pairs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input .txt file in the format.

```
Record  
ID||1  
Word||ABC   
Language||English   
Count||2   
Record  
ID||2  
Word||DEF  
Language||French  
Count||4
```

and so on.

I'm new to Apache Spark/Scala.

I see that there are options to read a file line by line by using the .textFile method or to read a whole file by .wholeTextFile method. We can also read files which are in CSV format.

But let's say I want to read such a file and create a case class out of it, which would have the members id, word, language, count, how can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input format is consistent (no random whitespaces, always terminates with "Record\n"), the following code works.

The key is in hadoop configuration's `"textinputformat.record.delimiter"`

```
case class Foo(ID : Long, Word : String, Language : String, Count : Long)
```

.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[*]")
conf.setAppName("stackOverflow")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","Record\n")

val rdd = sc.textFile("C:\\TEMP\\stack.txt")
  .flatMap(record => {
    if (record.isEmpty) None //needed to remove first empty string delimited by "Record\n"
    else {
      val lines = record.split("\n").map(_.split("\\|\\|"))
      //lines.foreach(x=>println(x.mkString(",")))
      Some(Foo(
        lines(0)(1).toLong,
        lines(1)(1),
        lines(2)(1),
        lines(3)(1).toLong
      ))
    }
  })
rdd.foreach(println)
```

The output is

```
Foo(2,DEF,French,4)
Foo(1,ABC,English,2)
```